# Why is my selenium not working? I keep getting an Attribute Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to get this to work for about an hour.

```py
body = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='Body']").send_keys("Body text")
```

I keep getting this error.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Comment: Use this driver.find_element_by_xpath you are using elements which returns list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bhavya Parikh said in the comments, `find_elements_by_xpath` *has an "s"*, meaning it will find *all elements with that xpath*, returning a list of web-elements. Use `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Body"]')` instead (it's recommended & easier to use single quotes around double quoted xpaths).

Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
userID = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="Body"]')[0].send_keys('text')
```

if you'd like to keep the same format.